# android getText error

Tags: android, eclipse, gettext

I am attempting to pull text from a TextView field as follows:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_random_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_medium"
        android:text=""
        android:textColor="#FF8800"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        tools:context=".ImHungry" />
```

The command I am using is here:

```
final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String search = R.id.text_random_text.getText().toString(); 
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://www.google.com/#q=" + search); 
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); 
                    startActivity(intent);
```

I seem to be getting an error which states that:
Cannot invoke getText() on the primitive type int

I am new to this so any help would be appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.id.text_random_text` is just the int id of your TextView.

You need to do something like:

```
public class Blah extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    TextView tv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        // blah blah
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_random_text);

         // blah blah

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == yourButtonsID)
        {
            String search = tv.getText().toString();
            // whatever you wanna do
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from CharSequence to String

Comment: Oh, oops. I forgot getText() returns a CharSequence. Doing `tv.getText().toString()` should work. =]

Answer (score 0):

you can't `getText()` from `int` type.

What you need to do is make a `TextView` variable

```
TextView random_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_random_text);
```

then on your `onClickListener` put :

```
String search = random_text.getText().toString();
```

Comment: I added that code and it seems to give me a force close on start now

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the String from the

`R.id.text_random_text`
which is nothing but the integer value. to take to String of the **TextView**, you have to 
do this.

```
 TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_random_text)
```

And then,

```
 button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String search = tv.getText().toString();
```